What are the allowed mime types for a users profile picture in Firebase?
The Firebase auth JavaScript client SDK has the updateProfile function, which takes a profile parameter that is described as follows:

profile: { displayName?: string | null; photoURL?: string | null }
The profile's displayName and photoURL to update.

What are the allowed MIME types to be returned following a request to the photoURL? The example uses a URL that ends in .jpg but I'd prefer to have an official source for what types are allowed. I wasn't able to find that in the documentation.

The photoURL field in Firebase doesn't actually store the image data, but merely stores the URL that refers to the image.
There is no limitation on the types of extensions the photoURL can have. In fact, many URLs don't have information about the image type embedded in them at all, and that is fine too.
